# Amazon AWS send email form RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, actionmailer

Am trying to send email from my RoR application using a remote smtp host.
This is working from my local server in both production and development.

when i set

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors
```

to true i get this error in the log

```
Error during failsafe response: 550-sender IP address xx.xx.xxx.xxx is part of Amazon AWS, and may not use this
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:964:in `check_response'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:933:in `getok'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:869:in `rcptto'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:850:in `block in rcptto_list'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:848:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:848:in `rcptto_list'
```

This is my settings for action mailer

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              "smtp.thehostname.com",
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'MyDomain.net',
  user_name:            'MyUsername',
  password:             'MyPassword',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  
}
```

and i have set this settings in my production environment

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "subdomain.mydomain.net" }
```

Does anyone know why I'm not able to send mail from amazon AWS?

Comment: Looks like your mail server has an access List to not accept any email from aws (which is a pretty good idea as aws can be a giant spam canon). But the fact that it is applying it to auth mail is a bit odd/annoyance. Not accepting unauthed mail from aws makes sense, but also blocking auth mail seems draconian. But your best bet is to talk to your mail server admin/host and see what they have to say as that 550 error is generated by your mail server (or so it seems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe EC2 restricts outbound SMTP traffic to prevent spam.  There's a [support request form](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request) to remove the limitations.

Or you can use [SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).

Comment: Normal is to restrict traffic to port 25 outbound to prevent spam cannons. But the this authenticated mail on submission port (587) so that normally isn't included in an outbound access list.